# Default intervals, timeouts, etc., for Pacemaker resource operations

Tags: pacemaker

Pacemaker resource agents mention default values for their operations' timeouts, intervals, etc., in their metadata. For instance, `crm_resource --show-metadata=ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2` lists some:

```
<actions>
<action name="start" timeout="20s" />
<action name="stop" timeout="20s" />
<action name="status" depth="0" timeout="20s" interval="10s" />
<action name="monitor" depth="0" timeout="20s" interval="10s" />
<action name="meta-data" timeout="5s" />
<action name="validate-all" timeout="20s" />
</actions>
```

Will these be taken as default values when I do not specify explicit values when configuring a resource (e.g. with `crm configure primitive ip_test IPaddr2 params ip=1.2.3.4 nic=eth0 cidr_netmask=32 iflabel=test`) or will I explicitly have to set them when I want to employ such defaults (e.g. with `crm configure primitive ip_test ... op monitor timeout=20s interval=10s`)?

My current assumption is that the second is the case, and that all timeouts, intervals, etc., will [normally default](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-operation-defaults.html) to 0 (not to any default values referred to in the meta-data) unless explicitly set otherwise. But I have not found any unambiguous statement in the [documentation](http://linux-ha.org/doc/man-pages/re-ra-IPaddr2.html), nor a command that would show me all relevant values (`crm resource show ip_nginx`), so I am reaching out to somebody who may know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeouts specified within the resource agent's metadata are not defaults, but rather the advised minimum values defined by the resource agents author.

The default value, if unspecified, is actually 20s as mentioned in the "[Clusters from Scratch](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_configure_the_cluster.html)" documentation:

> By default, the operation timeout for all resources' start, stop, and monitor operations is 20 seconds. In many cases, this timeout period is less than a particular resource’s advised timeout period.

It is considered good practice specify timeout values. I will often specify values even when using the default 20s.